# Want to read Code from Windows Command Skipt(CMD) File and extract Information

Tags: java, cmd, extract

a specific directory receives some different files including some `.cmd` files.

Here is and example of one of these:

```
X_COMMAND=DELETE_DOCUMENT
X_DOCIDENTIFICATION=FREE
DTY=MSDS
X_DELIMITER=;
X_FollowingFields=STA;DTY;PRN;SID;CTY;LAN;VKG
V;MSDS;340000021613012300;800000000160;ES;E;ES00
```

I want to work with the last 2 lines of Code to extract Data:

```
String xyz = (the command to get 340000021613012300);
```

**The Question is: How do I get this Data?**

I have tried to look this up, but did not find anything regarding this issue. If you can help me with this or redirect me to the information I look for I would appreciate that.

Thank you for your time helping me here.

Comment: Just read the file and extract the data you want - For example https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Content -Path "C:\src\t\Get-LastLineData.txt" |" ^
        "Select-Object -Last 1).Split(';')[2]"') DO (
    SET "xyz=%%~A"
)
ECHO %xyz%
```

If your script could be written in PowerShell, it would just be:

```
$xyz = (Get-Content -Path "C:\src\t\Get-LastLineData.txt" |
    Select-Object -Last 1).Split(';')[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just `cmd`:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=;" %%a in (file.ext) do set "xyz=%%a"
echo %xyz%
```

(assuming you want the third token of the last line)